# How do I fix crystallized butter cream filling made with ghee?

Tags: filling

I made 9 times this recipe for filling Brave Tart's Homemade Oreos.  I made it exactly as the recipe stated, but even after 15 minutes in the stand mixer, it was grainy and chunky, not creamy.  I tried using an immersion blender, but it didn't work at all.  I tried reheating it, and it made it worse.

I probably shouldn't have tried making that much at once, but now I have 1,500 cookies to fill and I hope I can save this filling.  Any ideas?

Here's the recipe (9x the original):
54 oz. unsalted butter (melted, water cooked off and solids strained out)
3 T. vanilla
1 1/8 tsp. Diamond Crystal salt
76.5 oz. confectioners sugar

Strain the hot butter into a stand mixer bowl.  Add vanilla, salt, then sugar.  Beat until creamy (original recipe said for about 5 minutes).
Note:  This is meant to be used warm, as it sets up between cookies and is quite firm.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right expectations for "creamy"? From pictures like here, it looks more fondant like than creamy - smooth, but with grain. http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2017/08/bravetart-homemade-oreo-style-cookies-recipe.html. They even have a video, you can see the texure at about 2:30: http://www.seriouseats.com/videos/recipes/bravetarts-homemade-oreo-cookies-5538923611001

Comment: So, are you actually using ghee or are you using clarified butter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is, making a larger batch just may not work - especially since this recipe needs a lot of precision in timing.  Specifically, the need for it to be mixed while hot makes larger batches problematical.  The second point is, the recipe states it can't be made in advance - which makes maintaining it at temperature, or reheating if it cools too much during filling, very problematic.  For the future, I would recommend making each smaller batch sequentially.

Is there anything you can do to fix it?  Maybe not exactly as intended, but I think adding a bit, a little bit, of water may work - it should loosen the filling enough to reach creamy consistency.  At worst, this batch of cookies may have a softer filling - which is not a terrible fate, even if not ideal.  But if you use very less water, and heat the filling when re-mixing, especially with smaller batches, you may lose enough water to evaporation (in the heating and cooling) to minimize this effect.

I would suggest making a few very small test batches to see how the filling holds up to these ideas - how much water to add, if heating (post-water addition) helps the texture, if the taste is still good, even if the filling as-is would be okay once in the sandwich.

Comment: Point taken on the mega-batch approach--it sure doesn't always work.

Comment: Because of the quantity, I think the butter stayed too hot too long and somehow changed the sugar structure (as best I understand it), basically crossing the line into candy making.  I am trying the water fix, which seems to be working.  When I have evaporated as much water as possible without caramelizing the sugar, I'll try whipping it again.